# Why can't I use the `ty` macro matcher to construct a struct?

Tags: rust

```
struct A {
    x: i64,
}

macro_rules! foo {
    ($T:ty) => {
        fn test() -> $T {
            $T { x: 3 }
        }
    }
}

foo!(A);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=040676d8b1e679653c646ac8d3b0ab72&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

```
error: expected expression, found `A`
8 |             $T { x: 3 }
```

I know I can use `ident`, but I don't get why I cannot use `$T {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Foo` in `Foo { bar: true }` *isn't a type*. A type is something like `i32` or `String`, sure, but also something like `Vec<u8>` or `Result<Option<Vec<bool>>, String>`.

It wouldn't make any sense to write code like this:

```
struct A<T>(T);

fn main() {
    A<u8>(42);
}
```

You will need to pass in *both* an ident and a type:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($T1: ty, $T2: ident) => {
        fn test() -> $T1 {
            $T2 { x: 3 }
        }
    }
}

foo!(A, A);
```

Or you can cheat and use a token tree:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($T: tt) => {
        fn test() -> $T {
            $T { x: 3 }
        }
    }
}
```